# subir archivos de un sitio a otro

Tags: php, servidor

Tengo Dos sitios web, Uno en el que el usuario publica sus archivos y El otro quiero que guarde los archivos publicados pero no se de que manera. ¿como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Tu pregunta es amplia y tiene problemas de formato lo cual causaría su cierre, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: ¿Intentaste hacer usando funciones [`FTP`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.ftp.php)?